# Using a proxy for unsecure Mapquest layers in Leaflet L.tileLayer call

Tags: leaflet, mapquest, tile-layer

I have a web mapping client that needs to be secure and use only HTTPS requests for layers. I would like to include some basemaps such as Mapquest OSM and OpenSeaMap which do not (as far as I can see) have a HTTPS urls.

I have a proxy setup but I can't see any option with L.tileLayer to apply it to the layer.  Is there a way to call a Leaflet tileLayer through a proxy?

If I use L.esri.tiledMapLayer to call the service I get different errors presumably because these are not ArcServer published services so this is not an option.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried [Thunderforest](http://www.thunderforest.com/)?

The tile URL scheme looks to use https by default: `https://[abc].tile.thunderforest.com/cycle/{z}/{x}/{y}.png`

Comment: Thanks ghybs I will look at that layer for the next update. 

The viewer is now available at http://maps.marine.ie/infomarbathymetry using only esri layers as basemaps.

Answer (score 0):

I have tried adding a proxy for the layers that are ESRI which will allow a proxy option but it doesn't appear to fool Firefox or Chrome.

The url for the layer is change to https://server/proxy/proxy.ashx?http://server/arcgis/rest/services....but an error appears to say 'Loading mixed (insecure) display content "http://server/arcgis/rest/services..."

When I take out the http for the service url I get Network Error Forbidden error for the layer.

Comment: This appears to be additional information for the question, and not an answer.  You should edit your question and add this information there, and delete this answer.